# How to sift through specific items from a webpage using conditional statement

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've made a scraper in python. It is running smoothly. Now I would like to discard or accept specific links from that page as in, links only containing "mobiles" but even after making some conditional statement I can't do so. Hope I'm gonna get any help to rectify my mistakes.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def SpecificItem():
    url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/'
    Process = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(Process.text, "lxml")
    for link in soup.findAll('div',class_='')[0].findAll('a'):
        if "mobiles" not in link:
            print(link.get('href'))
SpecificItem()
```

On the other hand if I do the same thing using lxml library with xpath, It works.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
def SpecificItem():
    url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/'
    Process = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(Process.text)
    links = tree.xpath('//div[@class=""]//a/@href')
    for link in links:
        if "mobiles" not in link:
            print(link)

SpecificItem()
```

So, at this point i think with BeautifulSoup library the code should be somewhat different to get the purpose served.

Comment: remove the conditional statement, and print everything. what do you see?

Comment: Thanks sir,  Paul H for your reply. If i remove conditional statement, i can see all the links available in that page. In fact, with if statement and without if statement I can't see any changes in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problem is your `if` condition works a bit differently between BeautifulSoup and lxml. Basically, `if "mobiles" not in link:` with BeautifulSoup is not checking if `"mobiles"` is in the `href` field. I didn't look too hard but I'd guess it's comparing it to the `link.text` field instead. Explicitly using the `href` field does the trick:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def SpecificItem():
    url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/'
    Process = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(Process.text, "lxml")
    for link in soup.findAll('div',class_='')[0].findAll('a'):
        href = link.get('href')
        if "mobiles" not in href:
            print(href)
SpecificItem()
```

That prints out a bunch of links and none of them include "mobiles".

Comment: Thanks supersam654, for your answer. I was thinking exactly the way you described here but I could not get any idea to set the "href" command earlier print option. Thanks again and it solves the problem.